# The application crashes when using a class inherited from com.activeandroid.app.Application

Tags: android, activeandroid

I use my library Projects ActiveAndroid for which you want to create a class:

```
import com.activeandroid.app.Application;
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

on the emulator everything works fine, the data stored in the database and so on. but when you start the phone, the application crashes. and immediately.

Error:

```
01-29 12:55:19.027  14098-14098/com.skip.client.customer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.skip.client.customer, PID: 14098
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat21$SharedElementCallbackImpl
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:305)
            at com.activeandroid.ReflectionUtils.getModelClasses(ReflectionUtils.java:83)
            at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.activeandroid.Registry.openDatabase(Registry.java:149)
            at com.activeandroid.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:107)
            at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:8)
            at com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:9)
            at com.skip.client.customer.App.onCreate(App.java:12)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `getModelClasses()` in active android is trying to find a java class in your code that matches the model classes you would have specified in your AndroidManifest.xml.  Can you please post your manifest?  Specifically, I'm looking for a line like this:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_MODELS"
        android:value="
            com.example.myapp.Book,
            com.example.myapp.Chapter,
            com.example.myapp.Library
        "/>
```

If classes `Book`, `Chapter`, and `Library` are not defined in your code, then you'd get the no-class-def-found exception.

Also, I'd recommend changing your app to have your custom app class derive from `android.app.Application` instead of from the `ActiveAndroid` app base class.  And then explicitly initialize `ActiveAndroid`.  This will allow you to have your own exception handling around `ActiveAndroid.initialize()` and then explore why your exception is being thrown.  You can also use the debugger to step into the `initialize()` method and see where the exception is coming from.

```
import com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid;
public class App extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        // add your own exception handling around this.  Not that you can do much
        // in your app without a database, but at least you'd be able to log a
        // meaningful error to the log so you can know details about the exception
        // being thrown.
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
    }
}
```